# Bad request error with ruby google-api-client when querying Google Admin Directory API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am using version 0.6.4 of google-api-client ruby gem to query Google Admin Directory API.

Here is my session in ruby console:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'google/api_client'

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_ID = "SOME_STRING.apps.googleusercontent.com"
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "SOME_STRING@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = "/path/to/privatekey.p12"

key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, 'notasecret')
asserter = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.chromeos.readonly", key)
client = Google::APIClient.new
client.authorization = asserter.authorize
dir_api = client.discovered_api('admin', 'directory_v1')
resp = client.execute(:api_method => dir_api.chromeosdevices.list, :parameters => {'customerId'=>SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_ID})

resp.body
=> "{\n \"error\": {\n  \"errors\": [\n   {\n    \"domain\": \"global\",\n    \"reason\": \"badRequest\",\n    \"message\": \"Bad Request\"\n   }\n  ],\n   \"code\": 400,\n  \"message\": \"Bad Request\"\n }\n}\n"
```

I am probably missing something obvious here but it is unclear from the error response what is missing in the request.  Would appreciate any help/pointers in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar response in my C# program, listing users in my domain.

I still haven't resolved it but so far I managed to get the same error message in 
The APIs Explorer https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/admin/directory_v1/
when trying to do the same request there and omitting any value for domain.

That led me to believe that I somehow needed to add the domain to my request in my C#-code and by trial and error I *THINK* I found how to do it in C#.

But my suggestion is to try your API request in the APIs Explorer and then se if you could get the same error message there by NOT submitting the value for domain, as I think that's what the error-message means.

Comment: Thanks. Link to API explorer is very helpful.

A friend also pointed out that service accounts cannot access user information  (I somehow missed that part in the documentation).

I will try few other things and update this thread when I find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problems. I've wrote an example gist which explains how to set it up:

https://gist.github.com/thomaswitt/7468182

Steps are:

1. Go to Google Cloud Console (https://cloud.google.com/console)
2. Create Service Account with P12 File
3. Enable the Admin SDK in APIs.
4. Create a Project
5. Create a registered app within this project
6. Go to section 'Certificate' and generate a key
7. Download the JSON file as well
8. Go to the Apps Console > Security > Extended > 3rdPartgy OAuth
   (https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?#OGX:ManageOauthClients)
9. Add an API Client. Client name is value of client_id in the JSON
   file, API Scope is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly

Answer (score 0):

I found that [@JoBe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17774050/2737435) was pretty much on track. In Ruby, using the `Google-Api-Client` gem, you need to pass a hash to `list_users`, with the `domain`. i.e.

`UserService.list_users(domain: 'mydomain.com')`.